# JAVA - Why SwingWorker Thread not processing all publish strings?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea, swingworker

I am using a Worker class which extends `SwingWorker` and process **String** values in it's `process` method and prints them to a **JTextArea**.

So I am making a lot of `publish(some_string)` calls to print the strings to the text area, **but when I execute my Worker thread** - it doesn't print all the text I publish in the `doInBackground()` method. It misses a lot of publish calls, and I get only partial of the words I want.

**But** when I excute the thread and put a **breakpoint** and **follow it step by step** I can see that it does print **all the strings** from the publish calls.
Doing what it's supposed to do.

**Why is it working in debug mode but in normal mode it doesn't?**

My code:

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void , String>
{
    public Worker(int int optionOfWork){};

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        ...
        publish("Hellow");
        publish("This is a test");
        ...
        //  a lot of **publish(some_word) calls**   
        ... 
        publish("Some more words");

    }//doInBackground()


    @override
    protected void process(List<String> wordsToPrint)
    {
        String lastWordRecieved = wordsToPrint.get(wordsToPrint.size()-1);
        mainWindowTextArea.append(lastWord);  // not printing\appending all the words sent here by the publish calls
    }


    @override
    protected void done()
    {
        publish("\nDone");
    }

}//Worker class
```

All I am doing in the main thread is making a Worker object and excuting it:

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
```

and I start it using `worker.excute();`

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve], code that we can compile and run and that shows your problem for us.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. Ask if anything is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
@override
protected void process(List<String> wordsToPrint)
{
    String lastWordRecieved = wordsToPrint.get(wordsToPrint.size()-1);
    mainWindowTextArea.append(lastWord);  // not printing\appending all the words sent here by the publish calls
}

    @override
protected void done()
{
    publish("\nDone");
}
```

to this:

```
@override
protected void process(List<String> wordsToPrint) {
    for (String text: wordsToPrint) {
        mainWindowTextArea.append(text + "\n");
    }
}

@override
protected void done() {
    publish("\nDone");
    try {
        get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The for loop is generally how you process through the String list passed into the process method. Don't forget to call `get()` on your SwingWorker if only to check to see if any exceptions have been thrown. If still stuck, then yes, create and post that [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

You may need to put some `Thread.sleep(10)` between your `publish(...)` calls to prevent the calls from hogging CPU.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwingWorkerExample extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 40);
    private MyWorker myWorker;

    public SwingWorkerExample() {
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start Worker") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (myWorker != null && !myWorker.isDone()) {
                    myWorker.setLoopRunning(false);
                }

                myWorker = new MyWorker();
                myWorker.execute();
            }
        }));
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Stop Worker") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (myWorker != null && !myWorker.isDone()) {
                    myWorker.setLoopRunning(false);
                }
            }
        }));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
        private volatile boolean loopRunning = true;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000 && loopRunning; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000 && loopRunning; i++) {
                    String text = String.format("My Text %03d", i);
                    publish(text);
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String text : chunks) {
                textArea.append(text + "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            textArea.append("Done\n");

            try {
                get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setLoopRunning(boolean running) {
            this.loopRunning = running;
        }

        public boolean isLoopRunning() {
            return loopRunning;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwingWorkerExample mainPanel = new SwingWorkerExample();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingWorkerExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending only last published string (in given chunk)

```
 @override
    protected void process(List<String> wordsToPrint)
    {
        String lastWordRecieved = wordsToPrint.get(wordsToPrint.size()-1);
        mainWindowTextArea.append(lastWord);  // not printing\appending all the words sent here by the publish calls
    }
```

Change that to

```
     @override
        protected void process(List<String> wordsToPrint)
        {
            for(String part:wordsToPrint){
             mainWindowTextArea.append(part);
            }
        }
```

When you call `publish` that does not mean that `process` will be called right away. Rather that, published intems gets stacked, and passed as list of items in some point of time.

Comment: How is this answer different from the previous answer? He makes the same recommendation with the additional decent recommendation of being sure that `get()` is called.